# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting an error when trying to run `rake db:migrate`:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "plus_ids" of relation "comments" does not exist
```

I guess I did do some funky stuff when trying to remove the attribute plus_ids from my comment model. I'm not sure what is going on.

If I do a `rake db:reset` and then fetch the live database it all works locally again, but if I try to do a `rake db:migrate` it throws an error again.

How can I get rid of plus_ids properly so I can migrate?

Edit 1: Here's the migration files when I added (and removed) the attribute:

```
class RemovePlusIdsFromComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :comments, :plus_ids, :integer
  end
end
```

And then

```
class AddPlusIdsToComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :comments, :plus_ids, :integer
  end
end
```

They're in the wrong order in the migration list, not sure why.

Edit 2: I think there is something wrong with the Up/Down, if I run `rake db:migrate:status` I get this:

```
down    20150305203336  Remove plus ids from comments
down    20150305204404  Add plus ids to comments
```

Any way around this?

Comment: Could you please provide your migration file where `plus_ids` is migrated?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to run

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20150305204404
```

On both live and local, and then

```
rake db:migrate
```

On both again. Now the live and local database is in sync again, and migrating the database throws no errors.